# How to convert padded sequence tensor to expected RNN format?

Tags: python, recurrent-neural-network, chainer

I have a tensor of shape `(batch_size, max_sequence_length, embedding_size)` that is padded to maximum length to store sequences. I also have `(batch_size, max_sequence_length, vocab)`, for example:

```
# Batch size many, (batch_size, 4, 8)
[2,4,1,4]
[7,4,2,0]
[6,0,0,0]
# Using EmbedID(ignore_label=0) to get (batch_size, 4, embeddeding_size)
```

How can we pass this to for example a `NStepGRU` link in Chainer? and for example obtain the final hidden state of all the sequences `(batch_size, embedding_size)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NStepGRU` accepts a batch of sequences as a list whose element is of shape `(sequence_length, embedding_size)`. Note that padding is not needed here; each element can have a different length.

If you have a tensor `x` of shape `(batch_size, max_sequence_length, embedding_size)` and the lengths of the sequences `lengths`, you can pass `[x[i, :l] for i, l in enumerate(lengths)]` to `NStepGRU`.

`NStepGRU` returns `ys` the output of the last layer and `hs` the final hidden state. Since `NStepGRU` may contain multiple layers, the final hidden state is provided for each layer; i.e., `ys` has the shape `(num_layers, batch_size, embedding_size)`. If you are using single layer `NStepGRU`, just extracting `hs[0]` returns the final hidden state of shape `(batch_size, embedding_size)`.